# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery110102358926620800048' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I store a json object in HTML5 localStorage which is used to generate a number of different form fields.

```
   $(document).on('click','.checklistObject', function(){
        var allChecklists = JSON.parse(localStorage.checklists);
        var element_id = this.id;
        $.each(allChecklists,function(key,val){
            if (val.id == element_id) {
                displayChecklist(val, undefined);
            }
        });
    });
```

On first click on the unordered list which corresponds to the above, I this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery110102358926620800048' of undefined`

However on second click, it works, and everything fires correctly. This error is said to be found in the jquery.js see full traceback here "http://pastebin.com/RR9D6myx", but refers to one line in my code, this one:

`$('#content-body').trigger('create');`

Which applies the jQuery Mobile CSS-styling to the dynamically loaded content. Another thing which points to jQuery Mobile is that, if I load the original unordered without jQmobile styling, this error isn't present.

Edit: Below is the displayChecklist function:

```
function displayChecklist(checklistJson, previousSubmission){
    var createForm = $("#myform").dform(checklistJson);
    createForm.promise().done(function(){
         $('#content-body').trigger('create'); //apply jquery mobile styling
         $.mobile.navigate("#formpage"); //go to form page
         if (previousSubmission == undefined) {
            //console.log("previousSubmission is undefined!");
         } else {
            repopulateForm(previousSubmission);
         }
    });
};
```

Comment: Is element_id supposed to be the ID of the item you just clicked on? In that case, maybe this will help:

var element_id = $(this).attr('id');

jQuery tends to get upset if you mix up this and $(this) in my own experience.

Comment: @BasR. `this.id` = pure JS, `$(this).attr("id")` = jQuery.

Comment: post `displayChecklist()`.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that allows readers to reproduce your issue? (As a Stack Snippet or on jsfiddle.net would be a nice bonus, but the important thing is to have a *complete* code example that is as small as possible.)

Comment: @BasR. Tried changing to $(this).attr("id"). No change. Will keep that in mind thoough, cheers.

Comment: @Omar posted the function in the post

Comment: Problem was solved when I changed `$('#content-body').trigger('create')`, which was referring to the BODY tag of the whole page, to the ID of the actual list that needed to be refreshed. Thanks guys for all your input!